# order by and group by in ORM (fuelphp)

Tags: fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

I'm trying to order by and group by tag

> $result =
>   Model_Tag::query()->select(\Fuel\Core\Db::expr('count(*)'),'count')->select('tag')->group_by('tag')->order_by('count','desc')->get();
>
> $result =
>   Model_Tag::query()->select(\Fuel\Core\Db::expr('count(*)','count'))->select('tag')->group_by('tag')->order_by('count','desc')->get();

However, no matter what I do I get the error that the count is not defined as ORM insists on aliasing the field name:

> SELECT count(*) AS `t0_c0`, `t0`.`tag` AS `t0_c1`, `t0`.`id` AS
>   `t0_c2` FROM `tag` AS `t0` GROUP BY `t0`.`tag` ORDER BY `t0`.`count`
>   DESC"

Resulting in a column not found error

Alternatively:

> $query = Model_Tag::query()->select(\Fuel\Core\Db::expr('count(*) as
>   count'))->select('tag')->group_by('tag')->order_by('count','desc')->get();

query

> SELECT count(*) as count AS `t0_c0`, `t0`.`tag` AS `t0_c1`, `t0`.`id`
>   AS `t0_c2` FROM `tag` AS `t0` GROUP BY `t0`.`tag` ORDER BY
>   `t0`.`count` DESC

gives a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

In FuelPHP Version 1.8, access you controller and you query set this example:

```
$result = Model_Tag::query()->group_by('tag')->order_by('count','desc')->get();
```

if you get the count

```
$count = count($result);
```

Warning! Do not call your `select('tag')` because you are already using `Model_Tag`

Ref: https://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/database/usage.html